# iAd Test Ads not being displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, iad

I am not seeing test ads in a newly created application, and iTunes Connect states that the app is receiving test ads. I keep receiving an "ad inventory unavailable" or "unknown error" message. I have integrated iAd with multiple applications and have yet to come across this issue.

I triple checked all app setup steps.
- Created app id
- Created new development provisioning profile
- Created new app in iTunes Connect
- Enabled iAd in iTunes Connect
- Applied the provisioning profile in Xcode

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is a problem in iTunes Connect. I'm trying to set my iAd banner too and always the delegate returns the same error (ad inventory unavailable).

In addition, there is a problem that many people are reporting at this moment with iTunes Connect.

Try it in a few hours!

Comment: Been about 48 hours now and still nothing. Any luck on your end?

Comment: I have the same problem. I've just updated an app converting it to universal. It is in ad-hoc distribution, not submitted to AppStore yet and it is not receiving test ads. The original app for iPhone is receiving live ads. I've tested with iAdSuite sample code and it is not receiving test ads (which worked fine a couple of months ago).